# Internet access using sim900

Tags: gsm, dial-up

I want to connect my raspberry system to connect internet via sim900 gsm modem for that i am using wvdial method to connect internet my wvdial configuration file like follows

```
[Dialer play]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 9600
Init1 = ATH
Init2 = ATE1
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com"
Dial Command = ATD
Phone = *99#
Stupid mode = yes
Username = ""
Password = ""
```

if i am connecting 3g usb modem using above configuration the output screen like this

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATH
ATH
OK
--> Sending: ATE1
ATE1
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Fri Jun 14 22:35:19 2013
--> Pid of pppd: 3145
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: Ęy
--> pppd: Ęy
--> pppd: Ęy
--> pppd: Ęy
--> pppd: Ęy
--> pppd: Ęy
--> pppd: Ęy
--> local  IP address 10.133.163.246
--> pppd: Ęy
--> remote IP address 10.64.64.64
--> pppd: Ęy
--> primary   DNS address 89.108.202.20
--> pppd: Ęy
--> secondary DNS address 89.108.195.20
--> pppd: Ęy
```

it was connected to internet but by using the same command for sim900 gsm modem the output screen like this

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATH
ATH
OK
--> Sending: ATE1
ATE1
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Fri Jun 14 22:35:19 2013
--> Pid of pppd: 3145
--> Using interface ppp0
```

that is it was connect but local IP address, remote ip address,primary DNS address,secondary DNS address not assigned so i am unable browse the internet please help me how to resolve this problem give me the guidance to resolve this problem thanks in advance